# Wordpress Coding Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Being a complete numpty at this....

I am having troubles getting the below code to work (just shows the white screen of death)

```
case 'venue' :
     if( self::isValid($atts['venue'])) {
        $output .= '<td>' . apply_filters( 'ecs_event_list_venue', tribe_get_venue(), $atts ) . '</span></td>';

          if( !empty(tribe_get_event_website_link()) ) {
          $output .= '<td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="' . tribe_get_event_website_link() . '">Bookings</a></td>';
          } else {
          $output .= '<td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="' . tribe_get_event_link() . '">Read More</a></td>';
                  }
          }
      }
 break;
```

The original code was

```
case 'venue' :
     if( self::isValid($atts['venue'])) {
        $output .= '<td>' . apply_filters( 'ecs_event_list_venue', tribe_get_venue(), $atts ) . '</span></td>';
                  }
    break;
```

This works fine..

Any assistance appreciated and respected!!

Comment: ddduuuhhh!  Removed but still white screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
if( self::isValid($atts['venue'])) {
        $output .= '<td>' . apply_filters( 'ecs_event_list_venue', tribe_get_venue(), $atts ) . '</span></td>';

    $is_value = tribe_get_event_website_link();
          if( !empty($is_value) ) {
          $output .= '<td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="' . tribe_get_event_website_link() . '">Bookings</a></td>';
          } else {
          $output .= '<td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="' . tribe_get_event_link() . '">Read More</a></td>';
                  }
          }
```

You can't use function return value like this.

Comment: You are a legend!!  Works great now - i can see what you mean now.  Thank you....